# Difference between View and Request scope in managed beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

What does the view scope mean? Can anyone explain about it, so that I can understand how it differs from the request scope?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

A `@ViewScoped` bean lives exactly as long as a JSF view. It usually starts with a fresh new GET request, or with a navigation action, and will then live as long as the enduser submits any POST form in the view to an action method which returns `null` or `void` (and thus navigates back to the **same** view). Once you refresh the page, or return a non-`null` string (even an empty string!) navigation outcome, then the view scope will end.

A `@RequestScoped` bean lives exactly as long a HTTP request. It will thus be garbaged by end of every request and recreated on every new request, hereby losing all changed bean properties.

A `@ViewScoped` bean is thus particularly more useful in rich Ajax-enabled views which needs to remember the (changed) bean properties across Ajax requests. A `@RequestScoped` one would be recreated on every Ajax request and thus fail to remember all changed bean properties. Note that a `@ViewScoped` bean does not share any data among different browser tabs/windows in the same session like as a `@SessionScoped` bean. Every view has its own unique `@ViewScoped` bean.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)
- [The benefits and pitfalls of `@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Comment: @sessionscope create lots of problems specially when it shares session with tabs in a browser. Thanks BalusC.

Comment: @Makky: Just don't use `@SessionScoped` for request scoped or view scoped data. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/