# How can `p:autocomplete` be made to show its selected value, after a postback (or, "partial" postback)?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra

***(java7,  jsf/mojarra v2.1.11,  primefaces v3.4.2)***

## Problem

I have a form with an `p:autocomplete` input field that the user is required to populate, along with other fields (shown, below).

Right now, ***after the page is returned with validation and/or required errors***, the value that the user has set no longer displays.   This is in contrast to all the other fields which still show their values that have been entered/set by the user.

## Question:

Why doesnt this field display the user entered value?  Can I force it to display the value?

(Again, initially, the selected value is visible in the `p:autocomplete` input box.  But, after the page is submitted and returned with validation erriors, the selected value is no longer displayed)

## The tag looks like this:

```
<p:autoComplete
    id="code"
    requiredMessage="code value required"
    converter="acConverter"
    style="overflow: hidden"
    maxResults="200"
    scrollHeight="150"
    dropdown="false"
    value="#{testBean.parmMap['code']}"
    completeMethod="#{testBean.codeListComplete}"
    var="entry"
    itemLabel="#{entry.split(':')[1]}"
    itemValue="#{entry.split(':')[0]}"
    minQueryLength="1"
    forceSelection="true">
</p:autoComplete>
```

Right now, if a user submits the form and the form is posted back with various form validation errors, then, even if the user has correctly selected from the `p:autocomplete`, the associated input field does not show what they have selected (although it is apparently saved in the request/memory).

---

---

---

---

---

***FYI - Below is more info if you need it (otherwise, you can just ignore it)...***

***index.xhtml...***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>test autocomplete...</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="queryForm">

                <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{testBean.validate}" />
                <p:panel id="queryPanel"  header="test autocomplete..." style="width:100%;">

                    <p:autoComplete
                        id="code"
                        requiredMessage="code value required"
                        converter="acConverter"
                        style="overflow: hidden"
                        maxResults="200"
                        scrollHeight="150"
                        dropdown="false"
                        value="#{testBean.parmMap['code']}"
                        completeMethod="#{testBean.codeListComplete}"
                        var="entry"
                        itemLabel="#{entry.split(':')[1]}"
                        itemValue="#{entry.split(':')[0]}"
                        minQueryLength="1"
                        forceSelection="true">
                    </p:autoComplete>

                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                    <p:commandButton
                        id="submit"
                        value="Submit"
                        type="submit"
                        update="@form"
                        process="@form"
                        action="#{testBean.submitQuery}"
                        style="width:150px;"
                        styleClass="button"/>

                    <p:commandButton
                        value="Reset"
                        update="@form"
                        onclick="location.reload();return true;"
                        process="@this"
                        actionListener="#{testBean.reset}"
                        immediate="true"
                        ajax="false"/>

                </p:panel>
            </h:form>

            <h:outputStylesheet library="styles"    name="query.css"      />
            <h:outputScript      library="primefaces" name="/jquery/jquery.js" />
            <h:outputScript      library="primefaces" name="/jquery/plugins/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js" />
            <h:outputScript     library="primefaces" name="/jquery/plugins/inputmask/maskedinput.js" />

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

***TestBean.java...***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIForm;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("testBean")
@Scope("request")
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    public TestBean()
    {
        parmMap = this.getParmMap();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("parmMap", parmMap);
    }

    public void reset(ActionEvent event)
    {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("queryForm:queryPanel");
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("parmMap");
        setParmMap(m);
    }

    public String submitQuery()
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("hitlistData");

        System.out.println("TestBean_________________________submitQuery()____________________parmMap contains:" + this.getParmMap().toString());

        if (this.getParmMap().isEmpty())
        {
            return "";
        }

        return "/page2.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    private static LinkedHashMap<String, Object> parmMap;
    public LinkedHashMap<String, Object> getParmMap()
    {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("parmMap");

        if (null == map)
        {
            map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        return map;
    }

    public void setParmMap(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map)
    {
        parmMap = map;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("parmMap", parmMap);
    }

    public void validate(ComponentSystemEvent e) throws ParseException
    {
        LinkedHashMap parmMap = this.getParmMap();
        UIForm queryForm = (UIForm) e.getComponent();
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        UIInput code_c = (UIInput) queryForm.findComponent("code");
        String code = (String) code_c.getValue();

        try
        {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(code))
            {
                code_c.setSubmittedValue("");
                code_c.setValid(false);
                fc.addMessage(code_c.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, code_c.getRequiredMessage(), code_c.getRequiredMessage()));
            }

            if (fc.getMessageList().size() > 0)
            {
                fc.renderResponse();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> codeList;
    public static List<String> getCodeList()
    {
        codeList = (List<String>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("codeList");

        if (null == codeList)
        {
            codeList = new ArrayList<String>();
            codeList.add("keyaaaa:valaaaa");
            codeList.add("keybbbb:valbbbb");
            codeList.add("keycccc:valcccc");
            codeList.add("keydddd:valdddd");
            codeList.add("keyeeee:valeeee");
            codeList.add("keyffff:valffff");
            codeList.add("keygggg:valgggg");
            codeList.add("keyhhhh:valhhhh");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("codeList", codeList);
        }

        return codeList;
    }

    public void setCodeList(List<String> list)
    {
        codeList = list;
    }

    public static List<String> codeListComplete(String s)       //autocomplete "completeMethod"...
    {
        List<String> list = getCodeList();
        List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String ss : list)
        {
            if (ss.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
            {
                suggestions.add(ss);
            }
        }

        return suggestions;
    }

}
```

***ACConverter.java  (I created this in an unsuccessful attempt to remove the string value "null")...***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

@FacesConverter("acConverter")
public class ACConverter implements Converter
{
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(value) || String.valueOf(value).equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UIInput input = (UIInput) component;
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(input.getConverterMessage(),input.getConverterMessage());
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ConverterException(msg);
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        return (null==value?"":String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your bean is request scoped. Try going for view scoped instead. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025998/difference-between-view-and-request-scope-in-managed-beans)