# Is it safe to have inputHidden variables in jsf

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, request, hidden-field

I have a jsf page which have inputHidden fields whose values are flags to other functionalities (for instance conditional popup display,...) in my application. I want to know is it safe to have those values in hidden fields cant they be tampered in request or elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like as every other non-readonly/non-disabled input, they can be tampered.

If that's a concern, store those values in a view scoped bean instead.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)
- [Difference between View and Request scope in managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025998/difference-between-view-and-request-scope-in-managed-beans/)