# Initializing bean every time on <f:viewAction>

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, navigation, javabeans, forms

I am using jsf 2.2 from mojara 2.2.10 dependency.

My problem is that, in my viewscope bean, the initialize() function of `<f:viewAction>` tag's `action` attribute is called only when the page is loaded first time.(firebug inspect tells me that its a post(to the calling page) and then a get to the viewAction page).

I want to call it also after i submit a form which is on this page. From the `commandButton` that submits the form, i return a string `"/myJsfPage.xhtml"` without `&faces-redirect=true` because i want to return to the same page where the form was and not a different one.

The problem is that now {myBean.nameOfUser.size()} is not displayed and so is with other attributes. Also from debugging i know that initialize() is not called this time. The firebug shows only a get request when the submit button is pressed. I tried without onPostback="true" property but got no luck.

**EDIT**

My question is not about the placement of  tag. So it is not a duplicate. Anyhow, adding `<ui:insert name="metadata">` in the master template and than `<ui:define name="metadata">` in the .xhtml page does not solve my problem.

**My jsf page:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                template="../components/defaultLayout.xhtml">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{myBean.initialize}" onPostback="true"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:param name="bodyClass" value="container body-nomargin" />

    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-md-10">

            <h:form id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                **#{myBean.nameOfUser.size()}**

                <!-- Only this code works after form submission -->

                    <h:panelGroup class="input-group" layout="block">
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control" readonly="readonly"
                               onclick="$('#uploadform\\:file').click();"/>

                        <label class="input-group-btn">
                            <h:panelGroup
                                    class="btn btn-default">
                                <h:outputText value="some value"/>
                                <h:inputFile id="file" value="some other value"
                                             validator="#{myBean.checkFile}"
                                             onchange="$('#uploadform\\:uploadBtn').removeClass('disabled');"
                                             style="display: none;"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:commandButton id="uploadBtn" value="Upload"
                                             action="#{myBean.uploadFile}"
                                             styleClass="btn btn-primary disabled"/>
                        </label>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:outputScript>
                        $(function () {
                            doUpload();
                        });
                    </h:outputScript>
                </h:panelGroup>
           </h:form>
```

**My javascript function from .js file is:**

```
function initializeFileUpload() {

    $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
        var input = $(this),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });


    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

            var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

            if( input.length ) {
                input.val(log);
            } else {
                if( log ) alert(log);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

**My Java Bean is:**

```
 public void initialize() {        
    setAllFilesOfUser(myDatabaseFunction());                   
 }

 public String uploadFile() {

    //SomeCode

    System.out.println(nameOfUser.size());
        return "/myJsfPage.xhtml";
 }

    //Few more methods and attributes with getter and setters
```

Comment: According to the JSF 2.2 documentation, the action method "signature must match public java.lang.Object action()" which your doesn't. Try to fix this first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using <ui:composition> templating, where should I declare the <f:metadata>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856847/when-using-uicomposition-templating-where-should-i-declare-the-fmetadata)

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't think so. Please refer to my edit.

Comment: I know it was not your explicit question (50% of the questions in SO are sort of 'wrongly formulated btw). But if the placement is  **'wrong'**, it might not work as expected. That is at least the understanding I (also) get from the duplicate.'Correcting' it would still be better...

Comment: @Kukeltje Ok. i added it as a best practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution although i still don't understand how it works.

From my function i have to return

```
"/myJsfPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

instead of just

```
"/myJsfPage.xhtml"
```

When i was checking it with `faces-redirect=true`, i was adding `&` in the url instead of `?` (very basic mistake - happened because i copy pasted it from somewhere where there was another parameter sent in the url along with redirect).

Now the firebug shows a post and then a get(which was previously missing) to the same page.

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242240/semantics-of-faces-redirect-true-in-commandlink-action-and-why-not-use) i understood that `faces-redirect=true` should only be added when redirecting to a different page after form submit. That is why i din't add it initially as i wanted to load the same page after form submit. May be some one can clarify this?

> "But more than often the result is just presented in the same page, if
>   necesary conditionally rendered/included. Only on successful submits
>   which absolutely needs to go to a different page (e.g. login/logout),
>   you should indeed be sending a redirect."

Comment: Now I read the answer I understood the problem... All is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668268/returning-to-same-view-in-backing-bean-should-i-return-null-or-empty-string-or. So effectively you should return an empty string or make the return param void