# JSF Default Navigation rule overriding all other navigation rules

Tags: jsf, navigation

my intention is to create a form that can query database and return the results of type List. The result should be return inside the same form
that will create commandlink specific to each record in the database result.

However when I try to follow the link generated I am getting the same page and the response is the same even after I applied navigation rules using the faces-config.

All my views are in html5 and using JSF name space. There are no explicit AJAX
request being used in my views.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
 

    //JSF Managed Bean
    //Filename :Index.java
    
        @Named 
        @RequestScoped
        public class Index implements Serializable {
        
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1234567890090L;
         
            public String actionFindLink(){      
                return "review";
            }
        
        
         public List getFindRequests(){       
        // Return Database result base on values from form submission of type List.    
    }
        }
```

client template snippet https://www.paste.org/flat/112063

```
<c:forEach var="req" items="#{index.findRequests}">
<tr>
<td><a jsf:action="#{index.actionFindLink()}" jsf:value="#{req.name}" >

<f:attribute name="rid" value="#{req.id}" />
<f:param name="rid" value="#{req.id}"/></a></td>

<td>${req.claim}</td><td>${req.response}</td></tr>

</c:forEach>

<c:if test="#{empty index.findRequests eq true}">
<tr><td>No Results</td></tr></tr></c:if>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `faces-config` for navigation. Return `null` to return to the same view. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668268/returning-to-same-view-in-backing-bean-should-i-return-null-or-empty-string-or

Comment: I am not trying to return the same view. The  commandlinks generated in the foreach section does not work. What I trying to do is carry the user to the review page when you click on it but instead it carries you to the same page.