# Example of spring using Pageable, Example and Sort accessing a JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, filtering, pageable

I searched everywhere for an example of a Spring piece of code using **simultaneously** these 3 JPA concepts, very important when querying :

- filtering - using `Example`, `ExampleMatcher`
- paging - using `Pageable` (or similar)
- sorting - using `Sort`

So far I only saw examples using only 2 of them at the same time but I need **to use all of them at once**. Can you show me such an example?

Thank you.

PS: [This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories) has examples for `Paging` and `Sorting` but not filtering.

Comment: Assuming you have not succeeded in adding the 3rd technique to an example already using the other 2: What problem did you encounter, when you tried?

Comment: I didn't find a way, that's why I am asking

Comment: I want to filter (with many fields from the entity) and do paging and sort in a web page and I cannot find a way to do that with Spring JPA. Found examples on sorting or filtering or paging but not them all together

Comment: Yes, you state that clearly in your question. I was hoping that you could provide some specific technical details for whatever specific problem you are facing (for example, a [mre]).

Comment: I will delete the question if there are ppl who are offended by it, but to me this is a site of good practices not a site where u debug other ppls code.

Comment: If you have found a solution (one which is different from the excellent answer by Yann39) then that is great, and you are always welcome to post it in its own answer. (I can't see any reason why anyone would be offended by your question. I see it was down-voted - perhaps because it does not have much in the way of specific details).

Comment: I had other questions that also werent much specific but they didn't get downvoted. Maybe today there was some stubborn user who just feel frustrated by it for some unknown personal reason. I mean what minimal reproducible example has this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025998/difference-between-view-and-request-scope-in-managed-beans

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, searching for news on title attribute, with pagination and sorting :

Entity :

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class News {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String content;

}
```

Repository :

```java
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Long> {

}
```

Service

```java
@Service
public class NewsService {

    @Autowired
    private NewsRepository newsRepository;

    public Iterable<News> getNewsFilteredPaginated(String text, int pageNumber, int pageSize, String sortBy, String sortDirection) {

        final News news = new News();
        news.setTitle(text);

        final ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
                .withIgnoreCase()
                .withIgnorePaths("content")
                .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING);

        return newsRepository.findAll(Example.of(news, matcher), PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("asc") ? Sort.by(sortBy).ascending() : Sort.by(sortBy).descending()));

    }
}
```

Call example :

```java
for (News news : newsService.getNewsFilteredPaginated("hello", 0, 10, "title", "asc")) {
    log.info(news.getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in the end after more research:

```
public Page<MyEntity> findAll(MyEntity entityFilter, int pageSize, int currentPage){
    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
        .withMatcher("name", exact()); //add filters for other columns here
    Example<MyEntity> filter = Example.of(entityFilter, matcher); 
    Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"); //add other sort columns here
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(currentPage, pageSize, sort); 
    return repository.findAll(filter, pageable);
}
```